# I need to decode a encoded php code

Tags: php, base64, eval, decode, encode

I need to decode a encoded php,

This coded with base64 and eval, I think,

Please help me
Thanks.

I need to decode a encoded php,

This coded with base64 and eval, I think,

Please help me
Thanks.

I need to decode a encoded php,

This coded with base64 and eval, I think,

Please help me
Thanks.

```
<?php   
if(!function_exists("T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29"))
{
    function T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E)   
    {
        $TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E = base64_decode($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E);    
        $T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29 = 0;    
        $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571 = 0;    
        $T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257 = 0;    
        $TF623E75AF30E62BBD73D6DF5B50BB7B5 = (ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[1]) << 8) + ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[2]);    
        $T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA = 3;    
        $T800618943025315F869E4E1F09471012 = 0;    
        $TDFCF28D0734569A6A693BC8194DE62BF = 16;    
        $TC1D9F50F86825A1A2302EC2449C17196 = "";    
        $TDD7536794B63BF90ECCFD37F9B147D7F = strlen($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E);    
        $TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85 = __FILE__;    
        $TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85 = file_get_contents($TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85);    
        $TA5F3C6A11B03839D46AF9FB43C97C188 = 0;    
        preg_match(base64_decode("LyhwcmludHxzcHJpbnR8ZWNobykv"), $TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85, $TA5F3C6A11B03839D46AF9FB43C97C188);    
        for (;$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA<$TDD7536794B63BF90ECCFD37F9B147D7F;)    
        {
            if (count($TA5F3C6A11B03839D46AF9FB43C97C188)) exit;

            if ($TDFCF28D0734569A6A693BC8194DE62BF == 0) 
            {      
                $TF623E75AF30E62BBD73D6DF5B50BB7B5 = (ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++]) << 8);      
                $TF623E75AF30E62BBD73D6DF5B50BB7B5 += ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++]);      
                $TDFCF28D0734569A6A693BC8194DE62BF = 16;     
            } 

            if ($TF623E75AF30E62BBD73D6DF5B50BB7B5 & 0x8000)     
            {      
                $T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29 = (ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++]) << 4);      
                $T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29 += (ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA]) >> 4);      
                if ($T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29)      
                {       
                    $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571 = (ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++]) & 0x0F) + 3;       

                    for ($T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257 = 0; $T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257 < $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571; $T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257++)        
                        $TC1D9F50F86825A1A2302EC2449C17196[$T800618943025315F869E4E1F09471012+$T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257] = $TC1D9F50F86825A1A2302EC2449C17196[$T800618943025315F869E4E1F09471012-$T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29+$T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257];       

                    $T800618943025315F869E4E1F09471012 += $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571;      
                }      
                else      
                {       
                    $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571 = (ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++]) << 8);       
                    $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571 += ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++]) + 16;       
                    for ($T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257 = 0; $T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257 < $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571; $TC1D9F50F86825A1A2302EC2449C17196[$T800618943025315F869E4E1F09471012+$T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257++] = $TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA]);       
                        $T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++; 

                    $T800618943025315F869E4E1F09471012 += $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571;      
                }     
            }     
            else
                $TC1D9F50F86825A1A2302EC2449C17196[$T800618943025315F869E4E1F09471012++] = $TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++];     

            $TF623E75AF30E62BBD73D6DF5B50BB7B5 <<= 1; 
            $TDFCF28D0734569A6A693BC8194DE62BF--;

            if($T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA == $TDD7536794B63BF90ECCFD37F9B147D7F)     
            {
                $TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85 = implode("", $TC1D9F50F86825A1A2302EC2449C17196);      
                $TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85 = "?".">".$TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85."<"."?";      
                return $TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85;     
            }
        }
    }
}
eval(T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29("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"));  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This PHP code has not been "encoded", it has been obfuscated (symbols' names have been changed to something meaningless) to prevent easy algorithm reading.

Thus, there is no way to "decode" it, but you can try to understand what this script does anyway.